# Which one of these headers comes from MSVCR100.DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, header, include, header-files

I'm working on a cpp app, works fine on the virtual machine im developing but in my laptop (XP without c++ redistributable package) it shows an error saying the app needs MSVCR100.DLL and it's not in the computer. I am not referencing the dll directly anywhere in the app so I guess it could be because of the headers included. I don't want to use this dll include, I'd prefer if the app works without it. These are the headers included:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
```

I tried commenting a few, but for commenting other I have to change too much code just for testing.

Which one of those headers comes from MSVCR100.DLL?

The project setting "Runtime library" is set to **Multi-threaded (/MT)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in the C library depends on it whenever you compile your program with Visual Studio 2010. So either you link statically with the C runtime, or you deploy the DLL with your application.

If you want to know, stdlib.h, stdio.h, cmath.h depend on it, and also probably a lot of headers depending on the C runtime are indirectly included in all your other headers. So I'd say all of your headers depend on MSVCR100.DLL.

Another solution is to have a Visual Studio 2008 + SP1 installed alongside 2010 (VC++ express 2008 works fine) and select "Toolset v90" in the project properties.

Comment: If my project setting "Runtime library" is set to "Multi-threaded (/MT)" shouldn't the dll be linked to the compiled exe? Or do I need to set something else to statically link everything on compile?

Comment: I removed some .lib from additional dependencies and it runs without the dll error now, and it still works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The MSVCR100.DLL is the C runtime library of Visual Studio 2010, I think. I suppose your labtop has no Visual Studio installed. So you got to supply this DLL with your application. It should be there on your development system.

Comment: MSVCR100.DLL is part of the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package, not really VS. But I said I'd prefer not to use or supply the dll.

Comment: Ok, VC and not VS, who cares. But you need to supply this DLL, as it implements the standard C runtime and without the C runtime C++ cannot live and no application works, I think. You could install said Residtributable Package on the labtop, which should bring the DLL with it. But if you do not have other dependencies, just delivering this DLL in the same directory as your exe should work and you won't get around that, as the option to statically link against the C-runtime was removed from the newer VS versions.